# Jackson ObjectMapper Universal Masking without Annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

Today I have a masking implementation in place in which I'll map an already serialized JSON string to a Map<String, Object> using ObjectMapper and then do a breadth-first-traversal. As I traverse I check against a map of fields that are to be masked and mask according to their masking strategy. Then once masked, I use ObjectMapper to convert it back to JSON.

I've been rethinking this, and I would like to re-implement so that if/when I want to produce masked JSON, I simply swap in a customized ObjectMapper and let the masking happen when it's originally converted to JSON.

I don't want to make developers annotate fields - as this masking is applied at the framework level in most cases (applied automatically via Spring Boot Starter). I want to have an opportunity to check the name of the field and mask it's value if needed. Does the Jackson ObjectMapper have something I can hook into to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Jackson ObjectMapper provides hooks that you can use to customize the serialization and deserialization of JSON. You can custom a class by extending JsonSerializer

i guess something like this but i might be wrong hope this help

```
public class MaskJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {
    
    private Map<String, MyMaskStrategy> ms;
    
    public MaskJsonSerializer(Map<String, MyMaskStrategy> ms) {
        this.ms=ms;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartObject();
        BeanDescription beanDesc = serializers.getConfig().introspect(serializers.constructType(value.getClass()));
        for (BeanPropertyDefinition prop : beanDesc.findProperties()) {
            String propName = prop.getName();
            Object propValue = prop.getAccessor().getValue(value);
            MyMaskStrategy strategy = ms.get(propName);
            if (strategy != null) {
                propValue = strategy.mask(propValue);
            }
            gen.writeObjectField(propName, propValue);
        }
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

then register this class to the ObjectMapper bean and use it

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addSerializer(new MaskingJsonSerializer(myMaskingObject));
mapper.registerModule(module);
```